# Problem with notification sound on Viber

Tags: sound, thinkpad, viber

I have some problems about notification sound with Viber on Ubuntu 14.04. I have a Lenovo Thinkpad E320 and I wanted to know how to resolve it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

My Viber didn't play any sound notification in my Sony Vaio with Ubuntu 14.04. I fix it changing the "Audio Output" on Viber Settings>Audio & Video.

I hope this can solve your problem too.

Best Regards,
Rachid

Comment: Hi Rachid, unfortunately it doesn't work. I don't have any other propositions about the audio... I just have audio Stereo analogic.  But thanks anyway for your help.